# How to get value of Dialog Form to form behined in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have windows application form on which i have Lookup (Search Form) which popups as Dialog Form on top of first Form. Through this dialog form's search value I want to see results in form behind. Like when I enter some search text in Dialog Form and click Find Button that Dialog form will close and results will be shown on form behind. Result can be shown in DropDown combo or grid or any control.

But the main thing is to get value from Dialog Form to Form behind.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to accomplish this is to have the Find button simply hide the form.  Then you can expose the result as a public property of the form and finally the calling routine can close and unload the form when it has gotten the result.

*In the calling form...*

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SelectorDialog As New myDialog
    SelectorDialog.ShowDialog()
    Dim result As String = SelectorDialog.Result()
    SelectorDialog = Nothing
    'do something with the result

End Sub
```

*In your dialog form...*

```
Private formResult As String

Public Function Result() As String
    Return formResult
End Function

Private Sub cmdFind_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdFind.Click
    formResult = "some result"
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

This is an easy way.  You can also wrap the whole thing up in a class as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `InputBox` ?
This pops up a modal dialog with a textbox and returns the entered string.

Comment: I am using another form not InputBox....On Dialog Form i have Grid Control which has list of companies.....and when i double click the name of any company in list that form must close and that company value must be shown in Combo in Form behind.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a parameter to a subroutine in the other form